# soap webservice call using Apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

i am new to invoking webservice (writting client side) using apache camel (Though I know about webservice, and writting code using CXF, spring template). 
Could anyone please help me in providing some good links for camel implementation of invoking webservice.

i also want to ask why would I use apache camel option instead of apache CXF (using wsdl2java tool and call webservice easily).

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample of calling a soap service using spring-ws component. You could also use cxf component to do this.

https://github.com/ganga-aloori/camel-practice/blob/master/src/com/practice/camel/webservice/ExternalServiceCallerRoute2.java

Camel is an ESB based on EIPs which provides various components(CXF being one of them) to integrate several systems. If your use case is just to consume a soap service in your application without any scope for integration then I don't pefer Camel in that case.

Thanks,
Ganga

Comment: The link provided is not working. Do you have any alternate source by chance?